# CSS & DIV alignment

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I'd be really grateful if anyone could help me to solve the following "trouble".

I have a list of textual items ("text" < div >); every text refers to an image

The aim is to let the image appear in the "image" < div >, when the mouse is over the related-text

This is the best I could do ...

```
<html>
<head><style>
div                  { border: solid 1px #000; margin: 0 auto;}
#image               { width: 250px;
                       float: right;
                       margin-top: 0px;
                       display: none; }
#text                { width: 750px;
                       float: left; }
#text:hover + #image { display: block; }
</style></head>
<body>
<div style="width: 1004px; height: 500px; background-color:#dedede;">
     <div id="text">Text-1 </div>
     <div id="image"><img src="image-1.jpg" width=250px/></div>
     <div id="text">Text-2</div>
     <div id="image"><img src="image-2.jpg" width=250px/></div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

... the problem is: how con I allow the image to appear always at the top of its < div >, without following the text ?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: are you asking how to make the image come before the text? if so just reverse the order of the divs so that the image div is first followed by the text div.

Comment: Thank you floor ... I was trying to anchor the image to the top of its < div >.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your situation but I'd replace
`#text:hover + #image { display: block; }` 
with

```
#text:hover + #image { display: block; position:absolute; margin-left:750px;}
```

That way the div will be always in the top right corner.

Comment: Thank you Ivan! Wonderful ... it's exactly what I was not able to do. So, you have solved my problem and I've learned something new. Many, many thanks !

Comment: You're welcome, just have in mind the new properties of this div in case you change your webpage layout and wonder why it's not in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same ID more than once in your HTML, so for this to work you would have to replace #text and #image with something like .text and .image using classes.

```
<div class="text">Text-1 </div>
<div class="image"><img src="image-1.jpg" width=250px/></div>
<div class="text">Text-2</div>
<div class="image"><img src="image-2.jpg" width=250px/></div>
```

Here's a demo of a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/cer95pqx/5/

Comment: Thank you Christian ! It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it's really a good  alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Just change Your CSS code for `#image` to:

```
#image {

    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    display: none;
}
```

And set `position` to `relative`, for parent `div` container.

```
<div style="width: 1004px; height: 500px; background-color:#dedede; position: relative;">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keku2d40/1/)

Comment: Thank you Mateusz ... another excellent solution .... I think I have a lot to study :-) Thank you very much.